# How to get value ot global setting into singleton object method?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a following problem with sbt. From sbt console I can get value of baseDirectory global setting.

```
> baseDirectory
[info] /home/georginaumov/Documents/hello
>
```

I added one task from build.sbt

```
lazy val printBaseDirectory: TaskKey[Unit] = TaskKey[Unit]("printBaseDirectory", "Print baseDirectory for the project", KeyRanks.ATask)
printBaseDirectory <<= streams map Tasks.printBaseDirectory
```

This is code for Tasks singleton object.

```
import sbt.Keys.TaskStreams
import sbt._

object Tasks {
  def printBaseDirectory(streams: TaskStreams): Unit = {
    streams.log.info("Here I want to print value of baseDirectory")
  }
}
```

But I cannot get the value. I tried many things and in fact the problem is that I cannot get  java.io.File from sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File]. 
How to solve the problem?

I tried

```
printBaseDirectory <<= streams map Tasks.printBaseDirectory(baseDirectory)
```

and

```
def printBaseDirectory(baseDir: sbt.File)(streams: TaskStreams): Unit = {
    streams.log.info("Here I want to print value of baseDirectory")
  }
```

into the singleton object but get following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
[error] Type error in expression
 found   : sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File]
 required: sbt.File
    (which expands to)  java.io.File
```

Edit:

Many thanks to Martin. I wrote a [article](http://georgi-naumov.blogspot.bg/2016/07/how-to-have-value-like-basedirectory.html) on my blog for people with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to define `Tasks` as:

```
import sbt.Keys.TaskStreams
import sbt._

object Tasks {
  def printBaseDirectory(streams: TaskStreams, dir: File): Unit = {
    streams.log.info(dir.getAbsolutePath)
  }
}
```

and in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val printBaseDirectory: TaskKey[Unit] = TaskKey[Unit]("printBaseDirectory", "Print baseDirectory for the project", KeyRanks.ATask)
printBaseDirectory <<= (streams, baseDirectory) map Tasks.printBaseDirectory
```

Or:

```
lazy val printBaseDirectory: TaskKey[Unit] = TaskKey[Unit]("printBaseDirectory", "Print baseDirectory for the project", KeyRanks.ATask)
printBaseDirectory := {
  Tasks.printBaseDirectory(streams.value, baseDirectory.value)
}
```

Using the `.value` macro is the preferred way.